# Json request with the help of php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to connect API after jwt token. But this my first time experience with API. So Company give me to codes On is "Generate JWT token" other is httpRequest with php. Company give me Object of class "$request = new HttpRequest();". But i don't know to work this object.

Create a jwt at your end to request a token (PHP).
Replace {CLIENT_ID}, {CLIENT_SECRET}  in php code.
This code works fine.

```
function base64url_encode($str) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($str), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
 
function generate_jwt($headers, $payload, $secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET') {
    $headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));
    
    $payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
    
    $signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded", $secret, true);
    $signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);
 
    $jwt = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
 
    return $jwt;
}
 
$headers = array('alg'=>'HS256','typ'=>'JWT');
$payload = array('aud'=>'https://s1.serviceaccountsapi.example.net/v1/{client_id}/api/token', 'iss'=>'CLIENT_ID', 'expiry'=> 3600);
 
$jwt = generate_jwt($headers, $payload);
 
echo $jwt;
```

To request in PHP:
This is not working. Because this object don't have class . So i don't know what i write in this class.

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://s2.serviceaccounts.example.net/v1/{CLIENT_ID}/api/token');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);
 
$request->setHeaders(array(
 'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
 
$request->setContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request->setPostFields(array(
 'assertion' => 'Bearer  {PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE WITHOUT BRACES}',
 'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'
));
 
try {
 $response = $request->send();
 
 echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
 echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: there is no class of  " new HttpRequest();".

Comment: HttpRequest is not a built-in class for php. you need find a library to handle network requests, or find another way to do it in php

Comment: I don't have experience in php. would you tell me what kind code i should write ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's proposing you to implement an HttpRequest class following the suggested interface.

Comment: Exactly. You need to implement it. Here is a great start point.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php